# Using service and ng-class on checkboxes click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-services, ng-class

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('checkCtrl', ['$scope','sharedService', function($scope, sharedService) {
     $scope.isCutScore = function() {
        if($scope.cc) {
            alert('Checked');
            $scope.val = true;
        } else {
            alert('Unchecked');
        }
    };
}]);


app.controller('divCtrl', ['$scope', 'sharedService', function($scope, sharedService) {

    $scope.addClass = function() {
        if(flag == true) {
            return EL;
        } else {
            return EP;
        }
    };
}]);


app.service('sharedService', function() {
    var flag = false;
    if(angular.element('#cutScoreCheck').is(':checked')) {
        flag = true;
    } else {
        flag = false;
    }
});
```

Add and remove class to a div using ng-class on click of checkbox. But challenge is checkbox and div to which we need to apply and remove class are in different controllers. And compulsion here is to use a service which is shared by both the controllers.
In the following example if we check the checkbox, 'EL' class should be applied and if we uncheck the box, this class will be removed and 'EP' should be applied.

[Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/zXt9aYl9Kpd1DCKTFEvi?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this. Works [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1C4vY7jcYLSXslYUrwIm?p=preview).

I have added function to service, it will be called  when user check the checkbox and I used `$rootScope` to reach AddClass method in different controller.

your body html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 checkDiv" ng-controller="checkCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cutScoreCheck" ng-model="cc" ng-change="checkDiv()"/>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 container" ng-controller="divCtrl" ng-class="flag ? 'EL' : 'EP'">500</div>
 </div>

  <script src="CtrlCheck.js"></script>

</body>
```

Js part:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('checkCtrl', ['$scope','sharedService', '$rootScope',function($scope, sharedService,$rootScope) {

    $scope.checkDiv = function(){
       var flag = sharedService.CheckDiv($scope.cc);
       $rootScope.addClass(flag);

    }

}]);


app.controller('divCtrl', ['$scope', 'sharedService', '$rootScope',function($scope, sharedService,$rootScope,$apply) {
  $scope.flag = false;
    $rootScope.addClass = function(flag) {
        if(flag == 'true') {
            $scope.divClass =  "EL";
        } else {
          $scope.divClass =  "EP";
        }
        console.log(flag)
        $scope.flag = flag;
    };

}]);


app.service('sharedService', function() {
    var flag = false;

    this.CheckDiv = function (isChecked) {
      if(isChecked) {
            flag = true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }

        return flag;
  }

});
```

Comment: Inside ng-class i aspire to have a conditional ng-class. Also classes 'EL' and 'EP' are not getting added on its click. @hasan

Comment: @SailyJadhav I have updated answer can you check again

Comment: Yup.. this is what i expected.. :)but just of of curiosity.. Can we skip the use of $rootScope. According to good practice only services and factories are used. @hasan

Comment: In this case you need to trigger another controller method after you called service method and there is no parent-child relation between your scopes of controller then you can inject $rootScope into the controller to call method from different controller